# Place button in dynamically created string

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to create a product page from products in a database. When I try to add a created button in the code it will only show "System.WebControls.Button" when I place it in the string.

Now I can see why this happens, but I can't think of a solution on how to add the real physical button.

My code:

```
Button in_cart = new Button();
in_cart.Text = "Put in cart";
in_cart.Click += new EventHandler(send_to_cart);
in_cart.ID = PRODUCT_ID //Product ID is filled in by the ID from the database

//Webstring consists out of more lines but this is the line where it goes wrong

string webstring = in_cart;
productHolder.InnerHtml = webstring;

    private void send_to_cart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clicked = (Button)sender;
        int id = int.Parse(clicked.ID);
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("startpage.aspx?ID={0}", id));
        //Going to startpage just for the testing
    }
```

Comment: What is `productHolder`?

Comment: The reason you see the text `System.WebControls.Button` is because doing `string webstring = in_cart;` doesn't get the HTML for the button. It calls the `.ToString()` function of the button, which in most cases only gives you the type name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a good way of doing things. It's preferable to avoid dynamically creating controls from the code behind (there are special considerations you must make when you do so). For the sake of this answer, let's avoid it.

## Single Product Page

Define the button on your .aspx page:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="in_cart" Text="Put in cart" OnClick="send_to_cart" />
```

Then in your code behind (.aspx.cs)

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    in_cart.CommandArgument=PRODUCT_ID; //assuming you load this from database
}

protected void send_to_cart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("startpage.aspx?ID={0}", in_cart.CommandArgument));
}
```

Notice I'm using the button's command argument to pass the product ID, because the ID of the button is how you refer to the button from the code behind, and we can't have that being dynamic. Also, your event handler has been made protected so that it can be properly wired up. Also, your naming scheme isn't very good, it should be more descriptive. Here's how I'd do it:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="AddToCartBtn" Text="Put in cart" OnClick="AddToCartBtn_Click" />

protected void Page_Load()
{
    //assuming you load product from database, possibly using Entity Framework
    AddToCartBtn.CommandArgument = product.ProductId;
}

protected void AddToCartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("startpage.aspx?ID={0}", AddToCartBtn.CommandArgument));
}
```

This is much more readable and descriptive.

## Multiple Product Page

The technique is similar for a page that is going to contain a list of products that are pulled from the database. Let's make use of a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx), which can databind to a list of products while still giving us a good degree of control over the HTML.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="ProductsRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Product Name: <%# ((Product)Container.DataItem).Name %><br />
        Product Description: <%# ((Product)Container.DataItem).Description %><br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="AddToCartBtn" OnClick="AddToCartBtn_Click" CommandArgument='<%# ((Product)Container.DataItem).ProductId() %>' />
        <hr /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

So that repeater will create the HTML for our objects. Let's wire it up now. Note that I put the data binding code inside an if statement that make sure it's not a postback to avoid rebinding the data.

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    if(!IsPostback)
    {
         List<Product> products=new List<Product>();
         products.Add(new Product(){Name="Toothbrush", Description="Fights cavities", ProductId="tb1"});
         products.Add(new Product(){Name="Vacuum Cleaner", Description="super vac!", ProductId="vac"});
         products.Add(new Product(){Name="iPod", Description="Plays your music.", ProductId="ipod"});

         ProductsRepeater.DataSource=products;
         ProductsRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void AddToCartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button=sender as Button;
    string productid=button.CommandArgument;
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("startpage.aspx?ID={0}", productid));
}
```

You'll need a Products class to go with this example. You can put it on the code behind or put it in Products.cs in your App_Code folder.

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public string ProductId {get; set;}
}
```

I built up a sample set of objects for you, but I assume you'll load those from the database (check out [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) for that if you don't already have a plan for that). If you don't want to use Entity Framework and just want to use plain [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.110).aspx), you can always bind to a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, but this is for 1 product right? What if I have it for 20 products?

Comment: The page you're placing this button on, is this a page that will show multiple products at the same time, or just a single product? Basically, it is an overview page, or a details page?

Comment: The first, a page that will show multiple products.

Comment: And is this page going to be displaying a static list of products (ex: you hand code all the products that appear on the page) or pulling a list of products from the database that you want to display (ex: The data could change and you want the list to be kept up to date with the database)?

Comment: Exactly the last one, products are not entered static. And I use specific attributes of a product to fill the page, which I pull from the database

Comment: Thanks for all the effort Mason!